# How do i make it so every number that is next to a zero divides by two?

Tags: java

Everything I have tried so far divides the code by 2 and it does it twice for some reason.

CSP-ARRAY
 An array inhabitant represents cities and their respective populations. For example, the following arrays shows 8 cities and their respective populations:[3, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1]Some cities have a population of 0 due to a pandemic zombie disease that is wiping away the human lives. After each day, any city that is adjacent to a zombie-ridden city will lose half of its population.Write a program to loop though each city population and make it lose half of its population if it is adjacent (right or left) to a city with zero people until all cities have no humans left.

```
package Arrays;

public class Project {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i = 0;
    boolean hi = false;
    boolean hi1 = false;
    boolean hi2 = false;
    boolean hi3 = false;
    boolean hi4 = false;
    boolean hi5 = false;
    boolean hi6 = false;
    boolean hi7 = false;
    int[] a = {3, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1};
    if(a[0]==0) {
        hi=true;
    }
    if(a[1]==0) {
        hi1=true;
    }
    if(a[2]==0) {
        hi2=true;
    }
    if(a[3]==0) {
        hi3=true;
    }
    if(a[4]==0) {
        hi4=true;
    }
    if(a[5]==0) {
        hi5=true;
    }
    if(a[6]==0) {
        hi6=true;
    }
    if(a[7]==0) {
        hi7=true;
    }
    int z=1;
    while(hi!=false || hi1!=false || hi2!=false ||  hi3!=false || hi4!=false || hi5!=false || hi6!=false || hi7!=false) {
    if(hi=true){
        a[1]=a[1]/2;
    }
    if(hi1=true){
        a[0]=a[0]/2;
        a[2]=a[2]/2;
    }
    if(hi2=true){
        a[1]=a[1]/2;
        a[3]=a[3]/2;
    }
    if(hi3=true){
        a[2]=a[2]/2;
        a[4]=a[4]/2;
    }
    if(hi4=true){
        a[3]=a[3]/2;
        a[5]=a[5]/2;
    }
    if(hi5=true){
        a[4]=a[4]/2;
        a[6]=a[6]/2;
    }
    if(hi6=true){
        a[5]=a[5]/2;
        a[7]=a[7]/2;
    }
    if(hi7=true){
        a[6]=a[6]/2;
    }
    System.out.println("Day "+i+": ["+a[0]+", "+a[1]+", "+a[2]+", "+a[3]+", "+a[4]+", "+a[5]+", "+a[6]+", "+a[7]+"] ");
    i++;
    }
        }
}
```

Comment: = is assignment so when you do hi2=true you are setting it to true. If you want to check just write `if (hi2)`

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Java, but here is my attempt.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Project {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = {3, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1};
    zombieApocalypse(a);

}


public static void zombieApocalypse(int[] array) {

    boolean keepGoing = true;

    int j = 1;
    while (keepGoing) {

        int[] arrayCopy = array;

        //first element
        if (array[0] == 0) {
            arrayCopy[1] = array[1] / 2;
        }

        //element in the middle
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {

            if (array[i] == 0) {
                arrayCopy[i - 1] = array[i - 1] / 2;
                arrayCopy[i + 1] = array[i + 1] / 2;
            }

        }

        //last element
        if (array[array.length - 1] == 0) {
            arrayCopy[array.length - 1] = array[array.length - 1] / 2;
        }

        System.out.println("Day " + j);
        //copies clone back to original array
        array = arrayCopy;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

        j++;

        int counter = 0;
        //for each element checking if every city is zero
        for (int element : array) {
            counter = counter + element;
        }

        //if each element value in every city is zero, we stop
        if (counter == 0) {
            keepGoing = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When I set only the last number to zero it prints the array infinitely, and doesn't divide at all. Do you know why that is happening?

Comment: @NickWirth . I checked both of the codes I posted, and that bug is not present. What code are you seeing that bug in?

Comment: never mind I got it to work, sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @NickWirth Not at all. I am new to Java and would love to attempt any intro to java homework problems you may have, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is pretty simple. Just go through the array and check previous and next value.

```
public static void calc(int[] arr) {
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
        if(arr[i] > 0 && arr[i - 1] == 0)
            arr[i] /= -2;

    for(int i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        if(arr[i] < 0)
            arr[i] = -arr[i];
        else if(arr[i] > 0 && arr[i + 1] == 0)
            arr[i] /= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you were going for.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Project {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 0;

    boolean hi = false;
    boolean hi1 = false;
    boolean hi2 = false;
    boolean hi3 = false;
    boolean hi4 = false;
    boolean hi5 = false;
    boolean hi6 = false;
    boolean hi7 = false;

    int[] a = {3, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1};


    //the line of code below this comment is never used ever, what is it for?
    int z = 1;

    while ((((!hi || !hi1) || (!hi2 || !hi3)) || (!hi4 || !hi5)) || (!hi6 || !hi7)){

        if (hi) {
            a[1] = a[1] / 2;
        }
        if (hi1) {
            a[0] = a[0] / 2;
            a[2] = a[2] / 2;
        }
        if (hi2) {
            a[1] = a[1] / 2;
            a[3] = a[3] / 2;
        }
        if (hi3) {
            a[2] = a[2] / 2;
            a[4] = a[4] / 2;
        }
        if (hi4) {
            a[3] = a[3] / 2;
            a[5] = a[5] / 2;
        }
        if (hi5) {
            a[4] = a[4] / 2;
            a[6] = a[6] / 2;
        }
        if (hi6) {
            a[5] = a[5] / 2;
            a[7] = a[7] / 2;
        }
        if (hi7) {
            a[6] = a[6] / 2;
        }

        System.out.println("Day " + i + Arrays.toString(a));
        i++;

        /*if you want to update the boolean values after they are changed, then you have to include it within the block of code
        that is changing it. (if they are outside of this block of code, how will they ever update?)
        */

        if (a[0] == 0) {
            hi = true;
        }
        if (a[1] == 0) {
            hi1 = true;
        }
        if (a[2] == 0) {
            hi2 = true;
        }
        if (a[3] == 0) {
            hi3 = true;
        }
        if (a[4] == 0) {
            hi4 = true;
        }
        if (a[5] == 0) {
            hi5 = true;
        }
        if (a[6] == 0) {
            hi6 = true;
        }
        if (a[7] == 0) {
            hi7 = true;
        }

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each day iteration, you find the cities that have 0 population and push those indices to an array and let's name this array "indices". Then loop through this array and divide the population half only neighbor of these indices.  I write in javascript.

```js
    const inhabitants = (Arr) => {
      let day = 0;
      let A = Arr;
      // allEqual checks if the all elements in array is 0
      // when allEqual is true loop is over
      const allEqual = (arr) => arr.every((v) => v === arr[0]);
      while (!allEqual(A)) {
      // find the array[i]= 0 and push the "i" in indices
        let indices = [];
    
        for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
          if (A[i] === 0) {
            indices.push(i);
          }
        }
        // just divide the neighbor elements of element 0 
        for (let j = 0; j < indices.length; j++) {
          if (indices[j] > 0) {
            A[indices[j] - 1] = Math.floor(A[indices[j] - 1] / 2);
          }
          if (indices[j] + 1 < A.length) {
            A[indices[j] + 1] = Math.floor(A[indices[j] + 1] / 2);
          }
        }
    
        day++;
        console.log(`population on day ${day}`, A);
      }
    };
```